# Hibernate join statement instead of subselect

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I want to make hibernate generate a join instead of a subselect for querying collections but not the join that can be configured using FetchMode.JOIN.

Example tables:

```
root(id, property, <other_properties>)
layer1(id, root_id, <other_properties>)
layer2(id, layer1_id, <other_properties>)
layer3(id, layer2_id, <other_properties>)
```

and other tables for collections at the same level as layer1-3. Depending on the @Fetch(FetchMode.X) annotation I get

**FetchMode.JOIN:**

```
SELECT *
FROM root r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer1 L1 ON r.id=L1.root_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer2 L2 ON L1.id=L2.layer1_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer3 L3 ON L2.id=L3.layer2_id 
WHERE r.property=?
```

Which is a very wide result set with lots of duplicate data.
Plus one select per other collection per parent. E.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM other o
WHERE o.root_id = ?
```

**FetchMode.SUBSELECT**

is a bit better, as I get exactly one select per entity. Thus, the number of queries is limited by the number of entities defined and not the query result size.

```
SELECT L3.*
FROM layer3 L3 
WHERE L3.layer2_id IN (
    SELECT L2.id 
    FROM layer2 L2 
    WHERE L2.layer1_id IN (
        SELECT L1.id 
        FROM layer1 L1 
        WHERE L1.root_id IN (
            SELECT r.id 
            FROM root r 
            WHERE r.property=?
    )))
```

The root and layer1 table contain ~50M entries each, layer2 and 3 tables ~500M each. This results in very bad performance for the select above (~10min) on our Postgres DB.

Can I make Hibernate generate a 'bottom-up' join statement instead?

```
SELECT L3.* FROM layer3 L3
JOIN layer2 L2 ON L3.layer2_id = L2.id 
JOIN layer1 L1 ON L2.layer1_id = L1.id
JOIN root r ON L1.root_id = r.id
where r.property = ?
```

This query has the same result but can be executed in a couple of milliseconds.

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want inner joins instead of left joins, right? Well, just don't type the "left" in "left join". Where is your query?

Comment: The query looks like this: getSession().createCriteria(Root.class).add(Restrictions.eq("property", 1L)).list()

Comment: Sorry, corrected the SELECT statement above. There are two problems with this: 1. root, layer1, layer2 and layer3 are all selected within one statement resulting in a lot of duplicate data being transmitted from the db, 2. all other collections are selected in a seperate statement for each parent entity. Selecting multiple collections at the same time is not possible.

Comment: Why do you use a query that retrieves instances of Root if what you want (given your fast query in your question) is to get back instances of Layer3?

Comment: I want to get back all instances (lazily loaded) when I iterate through all the collections, starting with all roots returned. So Hibernate also generates a SELECT to get the Root entity, one for all Layer1 entities and one for the Layer2 entities. The queries for root, layer1 and 2 are fast enough so that I don't have a problem there. Just the last layer is way slower. Either because of the 500M entries in Layer2 or because the Postgres Optimizer stopping at Layer2.